# Jquery - hide all elements with ids that exist in a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes

I am using jquery to find out what the clicked elements `data-variants` is, using the following code:

```
<button data-variants="green blue red">Red<button>
```

```js
$('#topSelector').on('click', 'button', function() {
    var variants = $(this).data('variants');
});
```

Clicking button will set the variable to `green blue red`. I want to filter and hide all of the elements that have an id that matches one of the variants in the list. i.e hide any element that has the id `green`, `blue` or `red`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split the colors, then loop them and hide the elements

```
$('#topSelector').on('click', 'button', function() {
    var variants = $(this).data('variants');
    variants.split(" ").forEach(function(el) {
        $('#' + el).hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: It works but I get an error:
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #bottomSelector #

Comment: a better approach would be concatenating all ids to one selector, to it you can do whatever you want. var $selected =  $(#id1, #id2, #id3); - now if you want to .show() it you don't have to enumerate through them again.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert target string to selector string. First, convert string to array using [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and add `#` to start of every item of array using [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and convert final array to string by `,` delimiter using [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join). Now you can use result in jquery selector.

```
$('#topSelector').on('click', 'button', function() {
    var selector = $(this).data('variants').split(" ").map(function(val){
        return "#" + val;
    }).join(",");   
    $(selector).hide();
});
```

```js
$('#topSelector').on('click', 'button', function() {
    var selector = $(this).data('variants').split(" ").map(function(val){
        return "#" + val;
    }).join(",");   
    $(selector).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="topSelector">
  <button data-variants="green blue red">Hide</button>
</div>
<div id="green">Green</div>
<div id="blue">Blue</div>
<div id="red">Red</div>
```